# How do I get 3 Steaks in Level 2-6 while using only towers that cost 3 coconuts or less?

Tags: achievements, go-home-dinosaurs

> **Thrifty**
>
> Three Steak Level 2-6 using only cards that cost 3 coconuts or less

I am trying  to complete this achievement in Go Home Dinosaurs. I have the issue that the small stuff keeps running through and getting to the BBQ.

Can I "Three Steak" this level with my selection as shown in the screenshot below?
What tactics and cards should I use to accomplish this task?

[image: Screenshot showing my selection]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I refined my tactics and with this layout it finally worked:
[image]

Start at the lower left by drilling the two stones there once the level starts. Then pick up coconuts and place the stump gunners. After that, drill another 2 stones while killing the enemies in between.

Then continue to help out killing dinos with your gopher and place the rest of the gunners, while drilling stones in between.

I placed the ice machine fairly early, it helps out the top right gunner to deal more damage before the enemies pass. In the quite opposite to many other tower defense games, enemies do not slow down around corners.